# ROM回路のスイッチの仕組みについて

Tags: 電子回路

現在CPUの創りかたを読んでいます。
その中で、ダイオードの必要性と電流が流れが分かりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

左上の図では、スイッチが押されていないのでグラウンドに対して電流は流れないので出力2に対してOFFになって欲しいと思います。
しかし、その状態では電流が迂回して出力2には、スイッチが押されているように間違って認識されるらしいです。(左下の図)

私の疑問は、なぜ電流が迂回することで出力2がスイッチが押されていると認識されるのでしょうか？
別のスイッチが押されている回路を通すと、出力2がスイッチを押されているという意味なのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記の画像のように、私が矢印で書いた回路がある限り電流が流れるので、特段スイッチが押されている回路であるか否かは関係ないように思います。
また、この回路でスイッチが押されているかいないかは、見えない出力の先でプルアップ接続等が配置されているのでしょうか？

是非ご教授宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 私が矢印で書いた回路

そこは線が繋がっていません
回路図で交差する線がつながっている場合は交点に・を書きます

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。私が、書いた矢印の記号は物理的に線が繋がっていないので電気が流れないということなのですね。線が繋がっている所だけ、・があるということを理解しました。ずっと悩んでいたので有難うございます。

Comment: 解決しましたか?

Comment: 実際に線がつながっている特定の３つを同時ONしたら、対応する４つ目がONしたことになるわけですが、そっちはきっちり納得できましたか？

Comment: 解決致しました。皆様コメント、ご教授ありがとうございます。